# how to place an image over another image in android by onclick?

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

i have an imageview in my xml file and i want to put another image over it where user clicks.
i have used a canvas to place an image where user clicks but i am stuck when it comes to putting the canvas over my imageview.
Or is there any way around when we want to put another image over an imageview while detecting user clicks?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you opting to put an ImageView on top of an ImageView, could you not just change the image within the original ImageView? Failing that you could use a ViewSwitcher with two ImageViews and switch between.

Comment: actually i am trying to put a small image over an already placed big image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already overriding a `View` method, I would say have that draw the image rather than an `ImageView`.  Your `onDraw()` method would essentially be:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawBitmap(bottomBitmap, xCorner, yCorner, paintObject);
  canvas.drawBitmap(topImage, fingerXCorner, fingerYCorner, paintObject);
}
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, if you want to keep the `ImageView` because of the convenient scaletypes, then you can override a `FrameLayout`. Place the `ImageView` inside of it, then override the `draw()` method to draw a bitmap.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.draw(canvas); // draws everything in the FrameLayout
  canvas.drawBitmap(topImage, fingerXCorner, fingerYCorner, paintObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks , using the frame layout fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)?

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:src="@drawable/yourImageFile" />
```

Then define your `onButtonClick` method in your `Activity`,

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    /* Do something */
}
```